# Issue with echo command

Tags: unix, echo

i am having an issue with echo command, it is printing the value twice. Can someone please help in this?

Note: stats.txt is a dos file. i coverted it to unix by using dos2unix -437

```
file=`cat stats.txt | head -3 |tail -1`
stat=`cat stats.txt | head -4 |tail -1`

echo "$file,$stat"
```

Output:

```
+ echo -n 764,6
-n 764,6
```

Comment: Have you tried `printf` instead of echo?

Comment: $file,$stat? Also, why + echo? is + the command line thingy? Could you please show stats.txt? I feel like it may help with this problem.

Comment: How many lines does the file contain?

Comment: i captured the execution using set -x

Comment: file is having 5 lines

Comment: printf also doing the same.. please find the below set -x execution output.   + printf 638,6
638,6+

Comment: If you ran with `sh -x` or equivalent, you should expect to see the echo line itself prefixed with `+` and then the data.  It appers that the `echo` you are using does not recognize the `-n` option; it likely uses `\c` at the end of the string as a way to suppress the newline. So, at the moment, what you've shown is what would be expected.

Comment: Your command `echo "Sfile,stat"` does not refer to the `$stat` variable. Do you mean `echo $file,$stat`? Please update your question to show us the actual command you're using. Are you using just `echo`, or are you using `echo -n`?

Comment: This: `cat stats.txt | head -3 |tail -1` is more simply written as: `sed -n 3p stats.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The line(s) starting with `+` are caused by the shell script being started with the `-x` option. I think this is a debugging feature; you can remove the `-x`, or maybe add `+x`, to turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

It would be useful to know what shell you are using, but try:

echo "${file},${stat}"

Comment: i am using /usr/bin/sh

Comment: same thing happened for printf also... + printf 638,6
638,6+